# How do I cut out an object with Inkscape?

Tags: image-processing, inkscape

How do I cut out a object with Inkscape? I have a photo of flip flops but I need to only have the flip flops cut out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the '**clip**' feature.

1. Open or import the picture you want to crop. Take the following as an example:
   [image]
2. Place another object *over* it. This new object should have the shape (boundary) of the final cropped image. The hexagon in the following:
   [image]
3. Select *both* (or all) the objects.
4. From the menus, select **Object** > **Clip** > **Set**. This should be the outcome:
   [image]

Another example:
[image]

Source of the images: [Inkscape Wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Scratchpad_clippingtutorial#Clipping)